# IsFullScreen propertychanged event in Template10 uwp apps

Tags: uwp, converters

Sometimes we need a hamburger- less page. We do that with the IsFullScreen property. Additional we want to use this IsFullScreen property for switching the visibility of always available common controls.

```
<UserControl  Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
</UserControl>

public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public bool IsVisible
  {
    get
    {
      return !SettingsService.IsFullScreen;
    }
  }
}
```

How could we attach the propertychanged event for the IsFullScreen property.

Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `SettingsService` class. and `RaisePropertyChanged();` (It's Necessary for [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/binding-markup-extension). or you can use Dependency Property instead)

Like this: In the `SettingsService` class

```
public class SettingsService : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static SettingsService Instance { get; } = new SettingsService();

    bool _IsFullScreen;
    public event EventHandler IsFullScreenChanged;
    public bool IsFullScreen
    {
        get { return _IsFullScreen; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsFullScreen != value)
            {
                _IsFullScreen = value;
                //
                RaisePropertyChanged(); //uses CallerMemberName
                IsFullScreenChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    #endregion
}
```

And in the `MyViewModel` class just add the property `Settings`.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SettingsService Settings => SettingsService.Instance;
    //
}
```

And in the XAML file: In `Binding` path write the property path like `Settings.IsFullScreen` (I used [ValueWhenConverter](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Converters#valuewhenconverter) to convert from bool to Visibility)

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:converter="using:Template10.Converters"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MyViewModel x:Name="MyViewModel " />
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <converter:ValueWhenConverter x:Key="VisibleWhenTrueConverter">
        <converter:ValueWhenConverter.When>
            <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
        </converter:ValueWhenConverter.When>
        <converter:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
        </converter:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
        <converter:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
        </converter:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
    </converter:ValueWhenConverter>
    <converter:ValueWhenConverter x:Key="VisibleWhenFalseConverter">
        <converter:ValueWhenConverter.When>
            <x:Boolean>False</x:Boolean>
        </converter:ValueWhenConverter.When>
        <converter:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
        </converter:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
        <converter:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
        </converter:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
    </converter:ValueWhenConverter>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <UserControl  Visibility="{Binding Settings.IsFullScreen, Converter={StaticResource VisibleWhenFalseConverter}}">
    </UserControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please explain how it works and why it address the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. We solved the problem as follows. Our SettingsService class is a part of the [Template10 uwp extension](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki). For data binding we use the MVVM Light toolkit. We broadcast a ScreenSizeChangedArgs

```
public class ScreenSizeChangedArgs : MessageBase
{
  public bool IsFullScreen
  {
    get; set;
  }
  public ScreenSizeChangedArgs(bool isFullScreen)
  {
    IsFullScreen = isFullScreen;
  }
}
```

message when the IsFullScreen property has changed.

```
public class SettingsService
{
  public static SettingsService Instance { get; } = new SettingsService();
  public bool IsFullScreen
  {
    get
    {
      return m_settingsHelper.Read<bool>(nameof(IsFullScreen), false);
    }
    set
    {
      m_settingsHelper.Write(nameof(IsFullScreen), value);
      Views.Shell.HamburgerMenu.IsFullScreen = value;
      Messenger.Default.Send(new ScreenSizeChangedArgs(value));
    }
  }
}
```

In the relevant view model we register that ScreenSizeChangedArgs message and handle the new IsFullScreen value.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public bool IsVisible
  {
    get
    {
      return m_isVisible;
    }
    set
    {
      m_isVisible = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("IsVisible");
    }
  }
  public MyViewModel()
  {
    //The event when the IsFullScreen property has changed.
    Messenger.Default.Register<ScreenSizeChangedArgs>(this, args =>
    {
      IsVisible = !args.IsFullScreen;
    });
  }
}
```

For the bool to visibility conversion we use a IValueConverter similar like that http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2011/11/14/null.aspx